# Can we create inter-queue level workflow in celery at a queue level

Tags: python, redis, celery, flask-celery

I have celery with python and i configured two queue at the same redis server with different worker.

So i have:

**queue-1 tasks handles by local-worker-01**

**queue-2 tasks handles by local-worker-02**

I have redis as a backend and broker.

I am trying to achive something like:

**1. When queue-1 is empty or completed all tasks meaning no pending tasks,  kick start queue-2 tasks?**

**Note: queue-2 tasks are dependent on queue-1 tasks (all of it)**

I am reading around grouing, chaining, chord etcetra. But at a queue level i am confused, maybe i need to spend more time around the same.
**Any literature direction is highly appriciated.**